# Define class outside of a factory function and dynamic inheritance

Tags: python

I have an factory implementation for dynamic inheritance, this script works fine I'm able to pass a parent class at runtime to inherit like so:

```
def some_proc_class_factory(proc_class_base, prop1, prop2, sp_id, group_id):
    class concrete_proc_class(proc_class_base):
        def __init__(self, proc_class_base, prop1, prop2, sp_id, group_id):
            proc_class_base.__init__(self, sp_id=sp_id, group_id=group_id)
            self.prop1 = prop1
            self.prop2 = prop2

        def main(self):
            self.do_something()
            self.get_some_data()

        def do_something(self):
            self.logger.debug("Here we go !")
            self.logger.debug(get_datetime_range(1440))

        def get_some_data(self):
            st, et = get_datetime_range(1440)
            self.logger.debug(get_performance_data(self.dbc, "users", "results", st, et))
    return concrete_proc_class(proc_class_base, prop1, prop2, sp_id, group_id)
```

But now I would like to refactor this defining the class outside of the factory function, to only have the return statement so that the class could be imported from another module, is this possible in Python? this should work on python 2 & 3

Comment: "so that the class could be imported from another module" - if another module tries to import the class, what should it inherit from? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Depending on what motivated you to try this, it might make more sense to have the factory function return the class instead of returning an instance.

Comment: yes right, the class depends of `proc_class_base` parameter to inherit from, this comes from a PR observation, they told me that defining the class outside should work, but that didn't work and I couldn't find a way to do it, so I think this isn't possible correct?

Comment: Unless there's some important context we're missing, it doesn't make sense to move the class definition outside the function.

Comment: How are the factory parameters `prop1`, `prop2`, etc. supposed to be used? You shadow them in your `__init__` parameters.

Comment: @Barmar it's just representative parameters of a linux process class, they will be used on another functions, this dummy snippet is just a pre-modeling pattern that I'm implementing on the legacy code

Comment: I agree with @user2357112supportsMonica that the class needs to be in the function so it can inherit dynamically from the factory argument.

Comment: right, thank you guys